# Xcode6 storyboard different images for each resolution

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimageview, xcode6, uistoryboard

One of the screens of my iPhone app has a static image(UIImageView added on top of ViewController's view). I have different images for iPhone4, iPhone5, iPhone6 and iPhone6 plus. Is there a way to configure different images for each device resolution in storyboard.

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @ Shamsiddin Saidov: I ended up programmatically checking if the device is iPhone5 or 6 and load appropriate images. For iPhone4, retina display and iPhone6 plus, just naming convention works (image.jpg, image@2x.jpg, image@3x.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new image set in `images.xcassets`:

- add iPhone4 image as @2x
- add iPhone6 plus image as @3x

iOS will then automatically use @2x image file for iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5s, 6
and @3x image file for iPhone 6 plus

Comment: I have images in different sizes for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. How can I configure different images for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can, you can use the .xcassets folder in you project.
If you press the '+' (in the .xcassets) icon in the bottom left you can add "new image set".

In there you can add images to 1x/2x/3x resolutions (1x is for non retina iphone 4, 2x iphone 5/6 is for retina display, x3 is for iPhone 6 Plus)

Comment: I have images in different sizes for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6. How can I configure different images for iPhone 5 and iPhone 6?

Comment: What matters is the "PixelPerPoint" that is if you add x2 image the image will fit all the devices that supports x2 display you can use this web service to create all the images you need for development http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by using an "Asset Manager" as the other answers have pointed to, and by using a "Vector" image. A PDF image is Vector, and both "Adobe Photoshop" and "Adobe Illustrator" allow you to "Save as..." PDF. So:

[image]

Comment: And Sketch support to export as pdf too.